# Even opening the file with "rb+" it isn't writing in binary

Tags: c, file, binary, fwrite, fread

I have this struct declared:

```
typedef struct {
char *TITLE;
char *AUTHOR;
char *PUBLISHER;
int YEAR;
char *LANGUAGE;
int PAGES;
float PRICE;
} Book;
```

And I'm trying to use the function below to write in **binary** a Book in a empty file called **"BD_Books.bin"**:

```
void InsertBook(Book *L){
FILE *arq = fopen("BD_books.bin", "rb+");
if(arq == NULL){
    printf("ERROR WHILE OPENING FILE!!");
    return;
}
int regFile = -1;

fseek(arq, 0, SEEK_SET); //setting "pointer" to the beggining of file
fscanf(arq, "%d", &regFile); //reading first integer from file
if(regFile == -1){ //if the file is empty
        fwrite(L->TITLE, sizeof(char), strlen(L->TITLE), arq);
        fwrite(L->AUTHOR, sizeof(char), strlen(L->AUTHOR), arq);
        fwrite(L->PUBLISHER, sizeof(char), strlen(L->PUBLISHER), arq);
        fprintf(arq, "%d", L->YEAR);
        fwrite(L->LANGUAGE, sizeof(char), strlen(L->LANGUAGE), arq);
        fprintf(arq, "%d", L->PAGES);
        fprintf(arq, "%f", L->PRICE);
        return;
}
```

I can write all the data the way I want, but the problem is that I have to write it in binary format, but the function os writing as a text.
Isn't `fopen("BD_books.bin", "rb+");` enough to tell `fwrite()` to write all the data as binary, since I'm opening the file with the "rb+" argument??

Comment: if you give `fwrite` an array with ascii values, it will write it to the file. What should it do if `L->AUTHOR`'s content is `"Charles Dickens"`? It writes the ascii (or unicode or other) to the file.

Comment: What makes you think the file is a text file? The fwrite()s write strings up to but not including the NUL byte, since you use strlen(). You need to add one if you also want to write the NUL byte.

Comment: fscanf is not being used properly.  these two lines: ' fscanf(arq, "%d", &regFile); //reading first integer from file
if(regFile == -1){'  should be: if ( 1 != fscanf( arq, "%d", &regFile ) )  Because the returned value indicates success/failure, not what is set into the parameter(s)

Comment: a just opened file will always have the file pointer at the beginning of the file, so the call to fseek() is completely unnecessary.

Comment: All of the data being to written to the file is ascii text.  so naturally, there is no binary (unreadable) in the resulting file.  suggest: 1) place some kind of separator between fields, like a comma or '\0' .  2) the only possible binary to write to the file would be if the raw (typically 4 byte) (float and int values) then do not use fprintf(), rather use the fwrite() for all values

Answer (score 2):

Because you need to use `fwrite()` and not `fprintf()`, `fprintf()` writes strings to the file, whose byte representation is the same as their string representation.

Try chaging

```
fprintf(arq, "%d", L->YEAR);
```

with

```
fwrite(&L->YEAR, sizeof(L->YEAR), 1, arq);
```

And also, `sizeof(char)` is guaranteed to be `1`, so using it adds unnecesary ugliness to the code, making it harder to read.

Answer (score 1):

I think instead of rb it should be wb, since you are writing to the file.